# How to get the selected CardView in a ListView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview

I have a `ListView` of `CardViews`. As you can see in the picture below, my cards have a vertical `ImageView` on the edge with gray default background. I want to change the color of that `ImageView`'s background dynamically based on if the item is currently selected or not. I'm using `ViewBinding`, so, the reference to my `ImageView` would be `binding.hightlightView`.

[image]

This is the code for my adapter:

```kotlin
class SectionListAdapter(private val onItemClicked: (Section) -> Unit) :
    ListAdapter<Section, SectionListAdapter.SectionViewHolder>(DiffCallback()) {

    private lateinit var binding: SectionItemViewBinding
    private lateinit var parentBinding: FragmentSectionBinding

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SectionViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        binding = SectionItemViewBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
        parentBinding = FragmentSectionBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return SectionViewHolder(binding)

    }
    
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SectionViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = getItem(position)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            onItemClicked(currentItem)
        }
        holder.bind(currentItem)
    }

    class SectionViewHolder(private val binding: SectionItemViewBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: Section) {
            binding.apply {
                sectionItemTitle.text = item.name
                generalPriceValue.text = item.priceNationalCard.toString()
                membersPriceValue.text = item.priceMembershipCard.toString()
            }
        }
    }

    class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Section>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Section, newItem: Section): Boolean {
            return newItem.id == oldItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Section, newItem: Section): Boolean {
            return newItem == oldItem
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should set the onClickListener in the viewholder that way you have easier access to the view to change the colour.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the section object with the onItemClicked listener with a flag like selected and update the adapter again with notifyDataSetChanged. Then in your binding look for this flag to select or deselect the item.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).